# Is it possible to render a widget based on the asset 'contains' relation?

Tags: thingsboard

I was wondering if ThingsBoard is able to render a dashboard where widgets dynamically show/hide based on sensors belonging to an asset.

For example:
A temperature indicator widget (e.g. Value card) is configured but only shows when a sensor of type "Thermometer" belongs to an asset, or a battery indicator widget only shows when a sensor of type "Battery sensor" belongs to an asset.

Another example would be; two temperature sensors belong to an asset, and therefore two temperature indicator widgets are rendered.

If this is not possible, is there a best practice to create a generic dashboard for an asset and render widgets according to its related sensors at all?

Else, every asset-device configuration requires a new dashboard.